Android Kotlin Worker Dependency Injection
When you inject dependencies into Android Worker and execute Worker Request, a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: newjeans.bunnies.main.worker.AwsS3FileUploadWorker. [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters] error occurs.
    fun awsS3FileUploadWorker(
        uri: List<CroppingImage>
    ) {

        // Constraints.Builder()를 통해 실행 제약을 설정할 수 있음
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            // 네트워크가 연결되어있는 상태일 때
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()

        val data = Data.Builder()
            .putStringArray(Constant.KEY_IMAGE_URI, uri.map { it.imageUri.toString() }.toTypedArray())
            .putString(Constant.KEY_POST_ID, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build()


        val awsS3FileUploadWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(AwsS3FileUploadWorker::class.java)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setInputData(data)
            .build()

        workManager.enqueue(awsS3FileUploadWorkRequest)
    }

@HiltWorker
class AwsS3FileUploadWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
    private val imageRepository: ImageRepository,
) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
        return@coroutineScope Result.success()
    }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class RepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideImageRepository(imageRepositoryImpl: ImageApiRepositoryImpl): ImageRepository =
        imageRepositoryImpl

}

